# How to convert txt file or PDF to Word doc using python?

Tags: python, pdf, ms-word, converters

Is there a way to convert PDFs (or text files) to Word docs in python? I'm doing some web-scraping for my professor and the original docs are PDFs. I converted all 1,611 of those to text files and now we need to convert them to Word docs. The only thing I could find was a Word-to-txt converter, not the reverse.

Thanks!

Comment: You can open plain text files with Word.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 But then how would he convert them? Opening 1611 files would be stressful.

Comment: Not my downvote. Why convert them if Word can open them anyway? What is the purpose for this?

Comment: What I'm wondering is why you need to convert any of them.

Comment: Could you clarify the purpose/intention behind converting text files to Word documents?

Comment: Converting plain text files into Word documents doesn't add any value. They can already be opened in Word, then modified and resaved in Word if necessary. If you just want the files to launch in Word when opened, all you'd have to do is give them the `.doc` extension (assuming Word is the user's default application for files with the `.doc` extension).

Comment: I disagree. There is great value to be had from automations of any kind. Have you ever written documentation ? If you have then, you should know how mind-numbing it is. That's where this would be awesome !

Comment: Hi, excuse me. Can I ask which tool did you use to convert all those 1611 PDFs to txt? Also if it is possible can you tell me that did you get all those PDFs from the universities' database or did you manage to download them somewhere on your own? Thanks very much!

Comment: @user2129773, I used pdftotext. It's a command line utility, so I used subprocess to run the tool from python. The PDFs were from txlottery.org.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using python-docx I was able to pretty easily convert the txt files to Word docs.

Here's what I did.

```
from docx import Document
import re
import os

path = '/users/tdobbins/downloads/smithtxt'
direct = os.listdir(path)

for i in direct:
    document = Document()
    document.add_heading(i, 0)
    myfile = open('/path/to/read/from/'+i).read()
    myfile = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+|\x0c',' ', myfile) # remove all non-XML-compatible characters
    p = document.add_paragraph(myfile)
    document.save('/path/to/write/to/'+i+'.docx')
```

Comment: I don't want to do formatting by my code. Is there any way which accept input file and covert that to .doc/.docx?

Comment: I just replace all your path with `path = 'd:\\2022_12_02'`  in all places, and it seems to see the text files, but those cannot be open. I get this error on open path: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'd:\x822_12_025g.txt`

Answer (score 3):

You could check out python-docx. It can create Word docs with python so you could store the text files into word.
See [python-docx - what-it-can-do](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#what-it-can-do)

Comment: Thanks. I'm checking it out. Other than installing it being a pain, it looks like it'll work.

Comment: I don't want to do formatting by my code. Is there any way which accept input file and covert that to .doc/.docx?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GroupDocs.Conversion Cloud, it offers [Python SDK](https://blog.groupdocs.cloud/2019/11/06/convert-pdf-to-editable-word-document-with-python-sdk/) for Text/PDF to DOC/DOCX converion and many other common files formats from on format to another, without depending on any third-party tool or software.

Here is sample Python Code.

```
# Import module
import groupdocs_conversion_cloud

# Get your app_sid and app_key at https://dashboard.groupdocs.cloud (free registration is required).
app_sid = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"
app_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Create instance of the API
convert_api = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.ConvertApi.from_keys(app_sid, app_key)
file_api = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.FileApi.from_keys(app_sid, app_key)

try:

        #upload soruce file to storage
        filename = 'Sample.pdf'
        remote_name = 'Sample.pdf'
        output_name= 'sample.doc'
        strformat='doc'

        request_upload = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.UploadFileRequest(remote_name,filename)
        response_upload = file_api.upload_file(request_upload)
        #Convert PDF to Word document
        settings = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.ConvertSettings()
        settings.file_path =remote_name
        settings.format = strformat
        settings.output_path = output_name

        loadOptions = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.PdfLoadOptions()
        loadOptions.hide_pdf_annotations = True
        loadOptions.remove_embedded_files = False
        loadOptions.flatten_all_fields = True

        settings.load_options = loadOptions

        convertOptions = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.DocxConvertOptions()
        convertOptions.from_page = 1
        convertOptions.pages_count = 1

        settings.convert_options = convertOptions
 .               
        request = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.ConvertDocumentRequest(settings)
        response = convert_api.convert_document(request)

        print("Document converted successfully: " + str(response))
except groupdocs_conversion_cloud.ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling get_supported_conversion_types: {0}".format(e.message))
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the code below. After run, the files will automaticaly be converted in .docx extension, BUT you will have to change the extension yourself after it.

```
# pip install docx
# pip install document
# pip install python-docx
# pip install Path
# pip install pathlib

import re
from pathlib import Path

from docx import Document

path = Path(r"d:\text")

if path.exists():
    print(path, "exists")
else:
    print(path, "does not exist")
    raise SystemExit(-1)


for file in path.glob("*"):
    # file is a Path object

    document = Document()
    # file.name is the name of the file as str without the Path
    document.add_heading(file.name, 0)

    # Path objects do have the read_text, read_bytes
    # method and also supports
    # open with context managers

    # remove all non-XML-compatible characters
    file_content = re.sub(r"[^\x00-\x7F]+|\x0c", " ", file.read_text())
    document.add_paragraph(file_content)
    # if Document could not handle Path objects,
    # you must convert the Path object to a str

    # document.save(str(file))
    document.save(file)
```

[SOURCE](https://python-forum.io/thread-39310-post-166687.html#pid166687)

Answer (score 0):

To convert simple plain text into docX can be done commando, without libs, that includes you running a customised OS shell script or as a text in/output in Python.

Note this is a draft (Proof of Concept) for you to tailor as required. My default is 54 lines portrait per page using Windows Consolas.

MS Word or WordPad is not required (but would help). Here showing a print preview from WordPad just to illustrate output, should you wish to auto print to PDF!.

[image]

The core function is xpdf/poppler `pdftotext -layout` which I will not describe more, as covered so many other places, to get simple plain text in different layouts.

So lets 1st "Round Trip" that text to PDF

lets see that in console:-
`pdftotext -layout -enc UTF-8 input.pdf -` (NOTE @ this time we Do NOT NEED to see page feeds)

undesired input

```
...

Line 53
Line 54
♀Line 55
Line 56
Line 57
Line 58
Line 59
Line 60
♀
```

So there are page feeds after line 54 and after line 60 (Lets save as output.txt without them **-nopgbrk**)

`pdftotext -nopgbrk -layout -enc UTF-8 input.pdf output.txt`

Now I did not say setup is easy but only needed once for thousands of files.
**CAUTION before leaping up and down shouting "Eurika" this simple method has one key common disadvantage (possibly more) that's mentioned [*] later**

A docX file is an archive zip folder with multiple parts . Thus our template needs to be a word working folder with the minimal components

WorkFolder

- Our script (for me its a MakeDocX.cmd which can be used to loop through files)
- output.txt (from pdftotext, in a batch run this would be constantly variable)
- *possibly* our input PDF (again a variable file could be overwritten)
- DocXheader.txt (this is the one where you set font name and height (24 units = 12 points)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
<w:body>
<w:pPr><w:spacing w:before="0" w:after="0" w:line="240" /><w:ind w:right="0" w:left="0" w:firstLine="0" /><w:jc w:val="left" /><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Consolas" w:hAnsi="Consolas" w:cs="Consolas" w:eastAsia="Consolas" /><w:color w:val="auto" /><w:spacing w:val="0" /><w:position w:val="0" /><w:sz w:val="24" /><w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
```

- [Content_Types].xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"><Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" /><Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml" /><Override PartName="/word/numbering.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.numbering+xml" /><Override PartName="/word/styles.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml" /></Types>
```

- A */sub folder* called `_rels` with a single file simply no filename but called  `.rels`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Target="word/document.xml" Id="pkgRId0" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" /></Relationships>
```

- Another */sub folder* called `word` which has yet another folder `_rels` and 3 documents.
  [image]

lets start with that sub folder, so it needs just one file unsurprisingly

- document.xml.rels

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Target="numbering.xml" Id="docRId0" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/numbering" /><Relationship Target="styles.xml" Id="docRId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles" /></Relationships>
```

Back to the word folder we don't need to worry about the `document.xml` since that is our now working target

- Numbering.xml has

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><w:numbering xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" />
```

- and `styles.xml` is similar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><w:styles xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" />
```

So it took me longer to paste this, than you will, to simply copy them.

So back to the script or other command system.

This is specially crafted for Windows but should be easy to follow and clone in any scriptable environment.

Simple MakeDocx.cmd   (with a known flaw, see [*] below.)

```
REM  Note for ""Windows Batch" we need to "escape" < and >, so other systems would not use ^< and ^>

REM copy header to initiate new document
copy /y DocXheader.txt temp.txt

REM  Now this is where your skill is required to read and write each line with a wrapper
For /F "tokens=*" %%L in (output.txt) do echo ^<w:p^>^<w:r^>^<w:t xml:space="preserve"^>%%L^</w:t^>^</w:r^>^</w:p^> >>temp.txt

REM  Finish of with a trailer
echo ^</w:rPr^>^</w:body^>^</w:document^> >>temp.txt

REM copy the new txt to the word folder as document.xml
copy /y temp.txt word\document.xml

REM now zip it all up and save to docX use tar exclusions to NOT include the "workings"
tar -a -c --exclude *.cmd -c --exclude *.pdf --exclude *.txt --exclude *.docx --exclude *.zip -f word.zip *.*
move /y word.zip word.docx
```

We have gone in a long loop but here is the pdf to DocX where we can see a different layout like Landscape ! There are expensive libraries that would struggle to do this with more finesse, however here is a zero cost system.

[image]

[*] During testing one simple plain text character caused failure in XML, and that was a raw `&` in the output.text from PDFtotext (which was `&`) Thus ALL `&` MUST be replaced with `&amp;`. There are likely other candidates that need similar text replacement. Luckily only 5 are listed
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML so we can easily use a replacement for those (in my case jrepl.bat handled the replacement) so afer pdftotext and before convert I have `jrepl "&" "&amp;" /F dirty.txt /O output.txt`

Answer (score -1):

```
# pip install docx
# pip install document
# pip install python-docx
# pip install pathlib
 
import re
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys
from docx import Document
 
# Locatia unde se afla fisierele
input_path = r'c:\Folder7\input'
# Locatia unde vom scrie fisierele docx
output_path = r'c:\Folder7\output'
# Creeaza structura de foldere daca nu exista
os.makedirs(output_path, exist_ok=True)
 
# Verifica existenta folder-ului
directory_path = Path(input_path)
if directory_path.exists() and directory_path.is_dir():
    print(directory_path, "exists")
else:
    print(directory_path, "is invalid")
    sys.exit(1)
 
for file_path in directory_path.glob("*"):
    # file_path is a Path object
 
    print("Procesez fisierul:", file_path)
    document = Document()
    # file_path.name is the name of the file as str without the Path
    document.add_heading(file_path.name, 0)
 
    file_content = file_path.read_text(encoding='UTF-8')
    document.add_paragraph(file_content)
 
    # build the new path where we store the files
    output_file_path = os.path.join(output_path, file_path.name + ".docx")
 
    document.save(output_file_path)
    print("Am convertit urmatorul fisier:", file_path, "in: ", output_file_path)
```

[SOURCE HERE:](https://neculaifantanaru.com/python-how-to-convert-txt-files-to-word-docx.html)